# How to detect multiple keys pressed at once

Tags: c++, qt, qkeyevent

I am currently developing a small 2D game with Qt C++.

The problem is that I can't catch more than 3 key pressed at the same time. I need this because I want to play with 2–4 players on the same PC, and on the same keyboard.
If I don't find a solution, my players won't be able to play at the same time, and that's a problem, because it's a real time game.

I am using the basic `keyPressEvent` to catch key pressed. Then I store the keys in a `QMap(int, bool)`, to know which key is pressed and not pressed.

I am also using a timer to treat the QMap values and do some actions when one or more keys are pressed.

The problem is when 3 keys are pressed and held down, and I press a 4th key, the 4th key is not caught, actually the program doesn't call `keyPressEvent` anymore.

**widget.h**

```cpp
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QtWidgets>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

private:
    QTimer *timer;
    QMap<int, bool> keys;
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
    void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *e);

private slots:
    void timerOutEvent();
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

**Widget.cpp**

```cpp
#include "widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    timer = new QTimer();
    timer->setInterval(1000/60);
    timer->start();

    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Widget::timerOutEvent);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{

}

void Widget::timerOutEvent()
{
    QString txt = "";

    if(keys[Qt::Key_Up])
    {
        txt += "u";
    }
    if(keys[Qt::Key_Down])
    {
        txt += "d";
    }
    if(keys[Qt::Key_Left])
    {
        txt += "l";
    }
    if(keys[Qt::Key_Right])
    {
        txt += "r";
    }

    qDebug() << txt;
}

void Widget::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    keys[event->key()] = false;
    QWidget::keyReleaseEvent(event);
}

void Widget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    keys[event->key()] = true;
    QWidget::keyPressEvent(event);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: For posterity, and because nobody has mentioned it yet, what you're interested in is called [Key Rollover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_rollover).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyboard is not a big block of keys. The keyboard is composed by groups of keys.

I explain:

1. You can't press all the four following keys : <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd> buttons at once.
2. But you can, for example, press the following keys at the same time : <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>, right <kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It makes 8 keys.

So to conclude, the keyboard is kind of multiple groups of keys.

Comment: This is the least satisfying answer I've ever read. Why are there groupings? What are the groupings? Are they the same for all keyboards or do some keyboards have different groupings? How can I predict whether two keys belong to the same group or a different group? There is literally no useful information here.

Answer (score -1):

This is a hardware limitation, you never need to use 5 keys at the same time, so why would the manufacturer to detect more than 4, some expensive keyboards manage more than 3-4 keys. Another way would be to plug 2 keyboards on the same computer or at least 2 Xbox/PS controller.

With my keyboard "Microsoft Wired keyboard 600", I could at least use 4 keys from the default layout and 2 from the Numpad, you could use your Numpad in your app.